# ZIP file from files with Danish characters in the filenames

Tags: c#, unicode, zip

I am trying to create a ZIP file from files with Danish characters in the filenames in C#. I have tried with both ICSharpCode, System.IO.Compression, and Ionic.Zip, but regardless I cannot get the Danish characters into the ZIP file.

I need the filenames to be exactly the same as the originals, because I am uploading the ZIP files to a program I have no control over.

It looks as though I should choose that the filenames be saved as Unicode with newEntry.IsUnicodeText = true but this gives me something like +ª+++Ñ+å+ÿ+à  instead of æøåÆØÅ when I open the zipfile in Windows Explorer. With IsUnicodeText = false I get æ¢åÆ¥Å which is close - only the ø becomes a cent character.

I get the same result from System.IO.Compression, and Ionic.Zip if I choose UTF8 encoding.

( I have also tried ZipConstants.DefaultCodePage = 850 - this does not help )

I can see that people have been struggling with this for years, but I don't see any clear answer. I would be grateful for any tips.

```
// this is the ICSharpCode version 
string fileToZip = @"Kontrolplan_15_Kørestrøm.docx"; // a file
        string entryName = "Danish Letters (æøåÆØÅ).docx";
        string zipPath = @"ZsharpZIP.ZIP"; 

        using (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream s = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipPath)))
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

            // ---- store statusPath
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileToZip);
            ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry newEntry = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry(entryName); 

            newEntry.Size = fi.Length;
            newEntry.IsUnicodeText = true; 
            s.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            // write file
            using (FileStream streamReader = File.OpenRead(fileToZip))
            {
                StreamUtils.Copy(streamReader, s, buffer);
            }
            s.CloseEntry();
```

Comment: I verified your findings: I created a ZIP file with .NET's ``ZipArchive`` class containing a file named 'Kontrolplan–15–Kørestrøm.txt'; ``unzip`` on Ubuntu on Windows shows the name as 'KontrolplanтАУ15тАУK├╕restr├╕m.txt'. If I create the ZIP file with an external utility, e.g. 7-Zip, ``unzip`` displays the name correctly as 'Kontrolplan–15–Kørestrøm.txt'. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a workaround in ``ZipArchive`` for this but I found the following that you may want to give a try: http://snipplr.com/view/47762/creating-and-reading-from-zip-file

Comment: It seems that Windows Explorer's built-in zip utility cannot handle UTF-8 file names. When I used 7-Zip instead, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Depends on the Windows version, I guess… Windows 10 seems to handle UTF8 names in ZIP files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Windows Explorer's built-in zip utility cannot handle UTF-8 file names. When I used 7-Zip instead, the problem disappeared.